# How do I add a method to the Form class in Windows Forms?

Tags: .net, winforms, methods

I want to add a new method in Windows.Forms.Form class..

Please help how to do this if anyone knows..

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? And how are Windows Forms and ASP.NET both related to your problem?

Comment: What method is it that you want to add?

Comment: i want to create a new method in windows.Forms.Form class
i am making windows form application in asp.net

just i want to know can i do this?
if yes than how?

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the .NET Framework. You *can* extend it. When you add a new form in Visual Studio, you will be creating a class that derives from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`. In that class, you can add all the methods you like.

Also, ASP.NET is used to create web-based applications, not Windows Forms applications. The two have almost nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 3.5 you can create extension methods to the Form class like so:

```
 public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static string Foo( this Form form, string param1 )
        {
            return param1;
        }
    }
```

Then later you can call (somewhere in the code for the Form of course):

```
var foo = this.Foo("bar");
```